# Does a Silverlight memory profiler exist?

Tags: .net, silverlight, memory-leaks, clr, profiler

CLR profiler does not seem to work with the Silverlight CLR. Does another memory profiler exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be one available yet. However, as [recommended in this forum thread](http://silverlight.net/forums/p/12623/49752.aspx#49752), you can convert your Silverlight app to a WPF application and profile that:

> There is no tool as of now but as a workaround you can easily create a desktop (WPF) version of your Silverlight client from the same code base and few tweaks (refer Scot's blog for an example on this - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-8-creating-a-digg-desktop-application-using-wpf.aspx) .  Once you are done with this you can run any performance profiler that works with WPF.

Not an optimal solution, but it sounds like the best option for now...

**Update:** Just saw a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/seema/archive/2008/10/08/xperf-a-cpu-sampler-for-silverlight.aspx) about XPerf which is a cpu sampler for Silverlight. Not exactly a memory profiler but a good tool for testing the performance of Silverlight apps...

Answer (score 3):

Here is memory profiling in silverlight using Xperf.

[Get GC Information](http://naveensrinivasan.com/2010/03/21/get-gc-information-in-silverlight-using-etw/)

Answer (score 3):

Try this one, it is very useful:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/index.htm

Bruno.

Answer (score 2):

VS2010/SL4 has a profiler now checkout:

http://www.nachmore.com/2010/profiling-silverlight-4-with-visual-studio-2010/

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140409025544/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/seema/archive/2010/01/28/pdc-vs2010-profiling-silverlight-4.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Though not a full blown profiler with a yummy GUI, you could use [Windbg + SOS](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/08/21/debugging-silverlight-applications-with-windbg-and-sos-dll.aspx) to debug your silverlight app, it would require a lot of manual work, but you can then walk your managed heap.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Atologic SilverProfiler. Available at [www.atologic.com](http://www.atologic.com).

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a memory profiler, but a performance profiler.

Answer (score 1):

Use Silverlight Spy
It has a Memory Profiler built in
[image]

Comment: Silverlight Spy will show you the current memory usage, but gives no indication of what types are using that memory.  If you're trying to debug a memory leak for example, it is of no help.

Answer (score 1):

I use free [XTE Profiler](http://www.xteprofiler.com/) which also works with Silverlight Standard and Out of Browser applications. Shows live memory usage as well.

Answer (score 1):

[**.NET Memory Profiler**](http://memprofiler.com/) starting from version 4.0 supports Silverlight profiling.

Highly recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Standalone CLR profiler has been updated to work with Silverlight so you don't need to have VS Premium/Ultimate.

[David Broman's CLR Profiling API Blog: CLRProfiler V4 Released](https://web.archive.org/web/20190114032249/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davbr/2011/02/01/clrprofiler-v4-released)

UI isn't that great, but it works.