# C# check silverlight object size at runtime

Tags: c#, silverlight, profiling, size

How can I find the size of particular object such as Rectangle, Canvas or Glyphs objects in my silverlight application?

can I use memprofiler or antz profiler on silverlight runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Related**: [Does a Silverlight memory profiler exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156507/does-a-silverlight-memory-profiler-exist)

Windbg with [SOS extensions](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/08/21/debugging-silverlight-applications-with-windbg-and-sos-dll.aspx) will work against silverlight.

SOS allows you to walk the managed heaps and look at all the objects in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Or at least you can try with [Silverlight Spy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy/download-silverlight-spy/) to see total memory consumption.