# Memory profiler for silverlight

Tags: silverlight, memory, profiler

Do you have any suggestion/idea of Memory profiler for Silverlight?

Comment: I found one more tool for memory profiling.

http://www.xteprofiler.com/

Hope this helps for people who are also searching for the same.

Comment: Dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156507/does-a-silverlight-memory-profiler-exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the standard memory profiling tools (memory GC and lifetime) in Visual Studio 2010 - but only the Ultimate and Premium versions. The support is only for command line profiling, so the basics go:

1. Open a Visual Studio command prompt
2. VSPerfClrEnv /globalsamplegclife
3. VSPerfCmd -start:sample -output:somefile.vsp
4. VSPerfCmd -launch:"c:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -args:""
5. VSPerfCmd -globalon
6. VSPerfCmd -shutdown
7. VSPerfClrEnv /off

The generated VSP will include memory statistics.

You can find more detailed information at: http://www.nachmore.com/2010/profiling-silverlight-4-with-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: Hi Oren, thanks for your update. I am using Professional version only and looking for a better UI profiler like ANTS.

Answer (score 5):

ANTS Memory Profiler 6 now includes Silverlight 4 profiling support:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/index.htm

(Disclaimer: I work for Red Gate and am biased as hell.)

Hope that helps!

Bart