# Silverlight Memory Usage

Tags: c#, silverlight

Is there a way to measure the current memory usage of the silverlight plug-in from within the client side C# code?

I am isolating a memory leak and it would be good to know the current memory usage of the plug-in.

For instance it could be logged to a file before I clicked a button that it was using '60 mb' and after I clicked the button it was using '70 mb' etc. I could then gradually add in controls and use this technique to quantify the leak.

---

As I mentioned above,

*I am more looking for a C# silverlight library call that I can call within my code to get the current memory usage at any particular point in time.*

So I am guessing that there isn't a way to do this?

In winforms (and WPF probably) I believe this is possible, but perhaps the stripped back nature of silverlight has excluded this functionality?

Comment: Did you check a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156507/does-a-silverlight-memory-profiler-exist ?

Comment: I am more looking for a C# silverlight library call that I can call within my code to get the current memory usage at any particular point in time.

Answer (score 1):

GC.GetTotalMemory might help you.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you: [Analyzing Silverlight Memory Usage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slperf/archive/2010/08/19/analyzing-silverlight-memory-usage-part-1-obtaining-measurements.aspx)

Comment: I am more looking for a C# silverlight library call that I can call within my code to get the current memory usage at any particular point in time.